# NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdklib/xml/ManifestData started appearing for unknown reasons

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry

This error suddenly started occurring on BlackBerry projects that worked a week ago, can't think of what could have changed in the past week. The error doesn't happen when I'm working on Android projects.

I've checked similar questions on the site and the path and classpath variables are fine. I also updated to the latest Java SDK, just in case something got messed up.
I'm running Windows 7 (x64), Eclipse (x64) and Java (x64).

***Here's the error log entry***

```
java.version=1.7.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
```

Error Tue Jul 10 00:53:40 EDT 2012
An internal error occurred during: "Launching UAV Coverage (1)".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdklib/xml/ManifestData

```
at net.rim.ajde.internal.launch.BlackBerryAndroidLaunchConfigDelegate.startLaunch(BlackBerryAndroidLaunchConfigDelegate.java:425)
at net.rim.ajde.internal.launch.BlackBerryAndroidLaunchConfigDelegate.run(BlackBerryAndroidLaunchConfigDelegate.java:326)
at net.rim.ajde.internal.launch.BlackBerryAndroidLaunchConfigDelegate.launch(BlackBerryAndroidLaunchConfigDelegate.java:308)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:937)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1141)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.sdklib.xml.ManifestData

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 8 more
```

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Android does not play well with java 1.7.  According to docs you should be using 1.5/1.6.  Maybe it's the same for BlackBerry?

Comment: The original problem occurred when java 1.6 was installed. I'll remove 1.7, reinstall 1.6 and see what happens.

Comment: The same error occurs with java SDK 1.6 installed.  Rob

Comment: Just had an idea...  should I install another copy of Eclipse in another directory and only use it for BlackBerry work? That way the working Android setup will continue to work.

Comment: Did you try installing the beta version of BlackBerry SDK Tools? http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Error-when-trying-to-debug-on-PlayBook-problem-with-new-ADT/td-p/1790751/page/2